# Unexpected ':infinity' argument appears in call to ':odbc.sql_query/2' in Elixir project

Tags: erlang, odbc, elixir

## Summary

I'm trying to query an SQL database in Elixir, via ODBC.

When running `:odbc.sql_query/2` with two arguments (see code example below), a third `:infinity` argument appears. This third, unknown argument causes a run-time exception:

```
C:\code\elixir_odbc>mix run
starting

13:44:37.212 [info]  Application elixir_odbc exited: exited in: MyMix.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :odbc.sql_query/3
            (odbc) odbc.erl:186: :odbc.sql_query(#PID<0.101.0>, "select count(*) from 'my-catalog'.my_table", :infinity)
            (elixir_odbc) lib/elixir_odbc.ex:23: ElixirOdbc.get_rec_count/0
            (elixir_odbc) lib/my_mix.ex:7: MyMix.start/2
            (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
** (Mix) Could not start application elixir_odbc: exited in: MyMix.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :odbc.sql_query/3
            (odbc) odbc.erl:186: :odbc.sql_query(#PID<0.101.0>, "select count(*) from 'my-catalog'.my_table", :infinity)
            (elixir_odbc) lib/elixir_odbc.ex:23: ElixirOdbc.get_rec_count/0
            (elixir_odbc) lib/my_mix.ex:7: MyMix.start/2
            (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

Where is this mysterious `:infinity` argument coming from?

## Details

In `mix.exs`, I'm including `:odbc` from Erlang/OTP:

```
  def application do
    [
      mod: {MyMix, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :odbc]
    ]
  end
```

In `/lib/elixir_odbc.ex`, I have the the following code:

```
defmodule ElixirOdbc do
  def get_rec_count do
    :odbc.start()

    case :odbc.connect(
           'dsn=my_dsn',
           []
         ) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        case :odbc.sql_query(conn, "select count(*) from 'my-catalog'.my_table") do
          {:selected, _colNames, [{count}]} -> IO.puts("Number of rows: #{count}")
          {:error, err} -> {:error, err}
        end

      {:error, err} ->
        {:error, err}
    end

    :odbc.stop()
  end
end
```

Also in `/lib/my_mix.ex`, I have the following mod, which implements the Application protocol:

```
defmodule MyMix do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    IO.puts("starting")

    ElixirOdbc.get_rec_count()

    Task.start(fn ->
      :timer.sleep(1000)
      IO.puts("done sleeping")
    end)
  end
end
```

The application compiles without any errors or warnings.

I get the same error when manually calling `ElixirOdbc.get_rec_count` from within the `iex` REPL, having started the application with `iex -S mix`.

If I run `odbc:sql_query/2` manually directly from the Erlang REPL (Eshell), then everything works fine and I get the expected data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

In my case, there are several database catalogs, so the call to `:odbc.sql_query` was liked this:

```
:odbc.sql_query(conn, "select count(*) from 'my-catalog'.my_table")
```

Notice that the string which is the second parameter is double-quoted, wherein the database catalog name (`'my-catalog'`) is single-quoted. That was the cause of this issue.

Apparently, the nested quotation needed to be the other way around.

After changing the call to this:

```
:odbc.sql_query(conn, 'select count(*) from "my-catalog".my_table')
```

Everything works as expected:

```
c:\code\elixir_odbc>mix run
starting
Number of rows: 70737

14:41:49.304 [info]  Application odbc exited: :stopped
```

I discovered the cause of this issue by going through by Eshell history and looking very carefully at the manual call I did (which was working), and discovered that I had reverset the quotations.